# String and StringBuilder difference

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Below is the code in Java:

```
package string;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromeString 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string: ");
        String s=sc.next();
        StringBuilder j=new StringBuilder(s).reverse();
        System.out.println(j);
        boolean b=s.equals(j);
        System.out.println(b);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

> Output: Enter the string: madam
>
> j=madam
>
> false

Why the output is *false* for this code?

Comment: StringBuilder is not a String class, so it should not be equals,

Comment: Note that `StringBuilder` is an utility object in order to create `String` objects, it is not a `String` itself. It is a bit like comparing *chocolate* to a *chocolate factory*. While *chocolate factories* produce *chocolate*, they are not *chocolate* themselves.

Answer (score 3):

The output is `false` because you're comparing a `String` object to a `StringBuilder` object. Although both `s` and `j` contain the same data, they are different object types, so they are never "equal". To make the answer `true`, you could change `j` so it's a `String` instead of a `StringBuilder`:

```
String j = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the result is false is stated clearly in the [`String.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) documentation:

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null **and is a String object** that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

You are passing a `StringBuilder` object to `equals()` instead of a `String` object, so the result is false, regardless of the characters.

`String` and `StringBuilder` both implement [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html), so you can use [`String.contentEquals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)) instead:

```
boolean b = s.contentEquals(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `String` to a `StringBuilder`. Of course it would be `false`.

Try `b=s.equals(j.toString());` This should makes `b` `true`.

Answer (score 0):

stringBuilder does not override Object's .equals() function, which means the two references are not the same and the result is false.

Comment: Is it `StringBuilder` that needs an `equals` in their example?